# Using analytics.js and the measurement protocol together

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm currently using Universal analytics.js with the enhanced ecommerce plugin in my store checkout.

When reaching the end of the checkout, I want to send the transaction data client side over the measurement protocol.

I'm wondering if this is at all possible to link up with the customers session created from analytics.js and if so, how?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably possible but it will be hard to do it IMO.

Session control is based upon the [cid](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) (and [uid](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid) if you are also sending that) sent with the request.

For you to be able to send these after the fact you are going to have to find a way of saving the CID analytics.js used This might help [Cookies and User Identification](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id?hl=en).  if you have the cid and send a request to the measurement protocol using that client id it *should* be considered the same user / session.

I have never tried this but in theory it should work.  If you do get it to work I would love to know :)

You might also consider adding some kind of custom dimension that would allow you to link the two requests.

If you are however using [session control](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl) once you have sent session end there is probably nothing you can do.  The session has ended I don't think you will be able to add anymore information to it.

Comment: If you want to continue a session from JS tracking code via measurement protocol you'll also have to set source, medium and campaign, since a change in traffic source information will restart the session. And you probably want to set the parameter for user IP (&uip) and user agent override. So I agree this is really hard to do (but still possible, I recall at least one Magento Module that did user tracking via JS code and order tracking via MP).

Comment: @EikePierstorff we should try and do this just for the fun of it :)

Comment: Since a buyer will probably be logged in, or in some way authenticated, one could assign a UserID - that should maintain sessions even when the client Id changes. We really should build a test case for this.

Comment: I can confirm after a bit of head scratching and a fair bit of testing that this is in fact possible. After looking at the payload sent from ga.js, I saved this data for the logged in user and later used it to send transaction data client side over the measurement protocol. Thanks again for your help. Hope somebody else can find this useful some day :)

Comment: @AaronHenderson did you include source, medium, campaign and IP with your MP requests?

Comment: @SilverRingvee all of that data is already recorded via the analytics.js tracking. By the time a visitor reaches the checkout there is no source, medium or campaign present in our url and so there is no need to send it via the MP(at least in my implementation). IIRC the client id (cid) was the important part. As were __utma and __utmz cookie values.